# "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Seeing "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" error when trying to run basic sample active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console.

Followed the steps in the Sample page in Github including giving "Read directory" permission as well for the Microsoft Graph Application in Azure portal

Tried the suggestion to give application "Company administrator" role but that throws another error "Access Denied : You do not have permissions to call this cmdlet"

Comment: You might be missing the consent step. Try the Microsoft Graph quick start here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/getting-started

Comment: Thanks! But the sample is failing at the first step when trying to get Tenant details. Consent is required if I try to do higher operations like reading user mail box etc?

Comment: Consent is required for getting an access token, which you need for any read/write query to the API